# Conversion from string to int metro apps c++

Tags: microsoft-metro

I am new to metro apps. My application contains two text boxes and I am trying to sum their values and display in another text box. But I am not able to convert the text read from text box to int.
Can anyone guide me on how to do this...

Comment: The standard C++ library is still available for this.

Answer (score 2):

String to numeric value:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof

Numeric value to string:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string